# How to change value of a HashMap while debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am trying to add a  key value pair to an existing hash map object while debugging but unable to to so..
I tried to add the below in change value object box but it says Hash Map cannot be resolved.

```
Map result = new HashMap();
result.put("Id","883LP07");
return result;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when your program stops at breakpoint, who result map as available -> write at any place in your code

```
result.put("Id","883LP07")
```

, mark it and execute rightMouse->Display

Comment: I was looking for a way to add  'live' value to a Properties file while debugging Java code in RAD and found this tip helpful. I used `properties.setProperty("K", "V")` in the Display window.

Answer (score 0):

Try qualifying the class name using `new java.util.HashMap` .